# How finally block works?

Tags: java, jvm, try-catch

hello community in my tutorial this week I found out that all threads stop when java gets a runtime error, but in the finally code block this event looks a bit strange.

```
public class main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {

    try {
        Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("enter number:");
        double val = Double.parseDouble(kb.nextLine());
        double result = MathUtil.myLog(val);
    }
    catch (MyException ex) {
        System.out.println("Cath:foo");
    }
    finally {
        System.out.println("foo:finally");
    }
}

class MathUtil {
  public static double myLog(double val)
{
    if (val < 0)
        throw new MyException();

    if(val == 0)
        throw new YourException();

    return Math.log(val);
}
class MyException extends RuntimeException {

}

class YourException extends RuntimeException {

}
```

When i execute this code and make an incorrect entry it first executes the finally block and then I get runtimeError.

Comment: That's the point: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/finally.html#:~:text=The%20finally%20block%20always%20executes%20when%20the%20try%20block%20exits.%20This%20ensures%20that%20the%20finally%20block%20is%20executed%20even%20if%20an%20unexpected%20exception%20occurs.

Comment: MyException will be printed first coz it is in the catch block. 

But YourException will be printed last after finally block, coz it is not in the catch block.

Comment: I don’t know where you got this “all threads stop when java gets a runtime error” from, but this is just wrong. Even if we try to interpret this as generous as possible, it’s still just wrong.

Comment: What do you mean by "incorrect entry"? Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: Just wanted to add that it does not stop all Threads. It only effects the current thread witch is not stopped it will just bubble up the frame stack until someone catches it

Answer (score 1):

Works as indented, doesn't matter if catch clause catch an error, finally as it says will execute almost every time. It won't execute only if JVM runs out of memory but it's rare corner case

Answer (score 0):

This works as designed :-) From the documantation from oracle:
'The finally block always executes when the try block exits..'
For me this means the finally block will be executed before the catch block or anything else is executed.

Comment: if there is error, catch block is executed first, then finally